# Team wide solution to track which branch was branched from which branch

Tags: git

I wonder if it's possible to have a hook or something like that, that you can setup team wide. The hook should keep track in a .txt file in the repo which branch was branched away from which branch.

We have a strict policy in our company that normally makes this not needed, but in very rare occasions it would be great to just look it up somewhere instead of trying to find merge points.

Comment: Try sourcetree application. It has a graphic display of which branch was branched away from which branch.

Comment: git merge-base give you the last common ancestor between two branches so no need to try to find, just ask git